# What can I do to get a dog to socialize with other dogs

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression

We are a foster for rescue dogs, and this weekend we were blessed to be able to save a momma dog and her litter of 9, 6 day old puppies.  The momma is a great dog, loves people, super attentive to her babies, and seems like a really great dog.  However she is not willing to interact with other dogs, and does not want them around her.

For the time being we have seperated her and the puppies in a bedroom downstairs where the other dogs are not allowed to go.  This is not my favorite solution because the momma is a bigger dog and I would really like her to be able to move about more freely.  This is also going to become more of a problem in a few weeks when the puppies start being able to move around and play more.

What can we do to change this behavior?  I think correcting this will make her a more adoptable pet after the babies are grown, and will make our lives much easier when the puppies get bigger, and I think it will improve her life as well.

Comment: I do not think it really matters, but the momma is a German Shepard mix with no signs of any bully breed in her.

Comment: Bully breeds are not naturally unsociable, so I don't know why you added that to your comment.

Comment: @jalynn2 - I agree with you, but others would disagree.  There is some statistical data however that backs up the reality that certain breeds have a higher incidence of agression.  But correlation is not the same as causation.

Answer (score 4):

You have a mother with a large litter of very young puppies that she will naturally be very protective of. She is probably a bit stressed just by nursing that number and trying to keep the nest clean. Now is not the time to bring other dogs into the mix. After the puppies are weaned, you can slowly introduce her to other dogs at a distance during walks, away from the puppies. If that goes well, you can bring them closer together for very short amounts of time, and gradually increase the exposure.

Comment: Plus one... she needs to get through raising the puppies first. If you try to make her socialize you can make things worse right now. Who knows, once the puppies are older you may find that she actually likes other dogs. Momma dogs naturally keep to themselves when they have young puppies.